# Is there a method for binding events to SVG elements like path using Svelte

Tags: svg, svelte

Is there a method for binding events to SVG elements like path using Svelte?

I have tried using `on:hover` on a path element and there is no effect.

Comment: In order to understand your problem better, you'd be better off providing some mininal example in StackBlitz or similar. I know SVG a bit, but I don't know Svelte. Nevertheless: perhaps you are trying to modify a SVG which is linked into the page instead of being embedded? That's however pure guessing - and it usually doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "hover" event, Javascript has "onmouseover" and "onmouseout".
so in svelte you would use `on:mouseover={handleMouseOver}`.
Here is a link to a svelte example with svg:
https://svelte.dev/repl/170a4929993247aba2b16f18621729ab?version=3.23.2